# How to mock/consider javascript prototype functions by default in jest test cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, prototype

**The following code throws error as : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`**

```
      this.setState({
        details: {
          ...this.state.details,
          [classificationType]: [value.trim()]
        }
      });
```

How to improve jest test cases to consider string features?

Comment: I guess it's event handler function that starts with something like `({ target: {value} }) => { ...` and you did not pass any object(with string value) while calling that event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be you are not getting `value` that's why it is unable to read trim() function on that. Can you please explain from where you are getting `value`? What mock data you used to execute your test case?

Comment: You are right, i updated from `value.trim()` to `value && value.trim()`